# In Mule 4,how can I save the data I retrieve from database using database connector?

Tags: database, mule, connector, mule4

Suppose I retrieve a row having a particular id using database connector.If I have to save a particular field lets say name in a variable for later use.How can I do that?

Comment: You need to be clear in your ask. if i understand from what you have posted, you would get an Array<Object> , most likely List<Map<>> returned from the DB connector. If you intend to obtain a column from the Map(s) in the list , you need to iterate over that and pick your Column and store the result in a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by `Save a Variable ID` ? Do you mean to store the retrieved ID information in a mule var ? If that's what you mean then try Salim's example. If col1 is the IDs you want, then result key captures it and store it in `col1` target variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very crude example would look like the one below:

[image]

You would need to go to the advanced section under the DB connector and you can configure the script to obtain the column values in the Output section.

[image]

Comment: Which studio version is this ? I didn't see configuration properties in a separate tab before. I usually see this in the the bottom of the general section.